When does a split mono factorize through an isomorphism to its image?
$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}$
Let $\C$ be a category with images, that is for every morphism $f: A \to B$ there exists a factorization $A \xrightarrow{e} I \xrightarrow{m} B$ with $m$ mono and which is initial with respect to all such factorizations.
Suppose we have a split mono $f: A \to B$, i.e. there exists $p: B \to A$ such that $p \circ f = 1_A$.
With my reasoning from sets, intuitively I'd like this to mean that $f$ "is an isomorphism onto its image", because "$p$ restricted to the image" gives an "inverse".
By which I'm asking that, in the image factorization above, the map $e$ is an isomorphism.
What are some necessary/sufficient conditions, either on the whole category $\C$ or on this individual diagram, for this to happen?
I think in the following cases, this does happen:

Sets
Toposes, maybe?
Abelian categories

so I'm interested in other, perhaps weaker, conditions.

If $f :A \to B $ is a monomorphism in any category, then $A \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}_A} A \xrightarrow{f} B$ is an image decomposition of $f$, as you can easily verify.
